# Changing Column Label format from datetime to date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, label

I have been trying to import data from an excel file where multiple column labels are dates. The excel file headers look somewhat like this

### Name 2018-08-01 2018-08-02 Amount

After importing it to a dataframe I got the column labels-

### Name 2018-08-01 00:00:00 2018-08-02 00:00:00 Amount

So I wanted to remove the hours from the headings. As the dates update automatically in the excel file so I can not replace the labels using '
df['2018-08-01 00:00:00']` I have tried renaming the columns using following code

```
df1.columns[3] =  pd.to_datetime(df1.columns[3], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

However this gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations.
```

I have also tried

```
df1.rename(df1.columns[3][lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%M-%d')])
```

Which gives the following error

```
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable
```

I am very new to Python and dataframe and I am still in the very basic stage. How do I get this done?

---

## Solved

As I already know the column index I converted them from `datetime object` to
`string`and then sliced them. I tried iteration but it was not working so this is the only way I could do it.

```
Edate=str(df1.columns[1])
Edatep=slice(0,10,1)
Gdate=str(df1.columns[2])
Gdatep=slice(0,10,1)

df1.columns=['Name',Edate[Edatep],Gdate[Gdatep],'Amount']
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexes in pandas are immutable - your best bet would be to make a new index.

I think here `list comprehension` working nice with converting only `timestamps` with `if-else`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', pd.Timestamp('2018-08-01'), 
                             pd.Timestamp('2018-08-02'), 'Amount'])
print (df1)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, 2018-08-01 00:00:00, 2018-08-02 00:00:00, Amount]
Index: []

print (df1.columns.map(type))
Index([                                     <class 'str'>,
       <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>,
       <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>,
                                            <class 'str'>],
      dtype='object')
```

---

```
df1.columns=[x.strftime('%Y-%M-%d') if isinstance(x,pd.Timestamp) else x for x in df1.columns]
print (df1)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, 2018-00-01, 2018-00-02, Amount]
Index: []
```

Another solutions if input data are strings:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.astype(str)

df1.columns = df1.columns.astype(str).str.replace(' 00:00:00', '')
print (df1)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, 2018-08-01, 2018-08-02, Amount]
Index: []
```

---

```
cols = pd.to_datetime(df1.columns, errors='coerce')
df1.columns = df1.columns.where(cols.isnull(), cols.strftime('%Y-%M-%d'))

print (df1)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, 2018-00-01, 2018-00-02, Amount]
Index: []
```

Comment: I can not do that as the dates would change every day, so I would need to set the Column names every day.

Comment: @Tasnuva - Not understand, if use `df1.columns = [x.strftime('%Y-%M-%d') 
               if isinstance(x, pd.Timestamp) 
               else x 
               for x in df1.columns]` it working dynamically witch changed datetimes too.

Comment: Sorry, I donot think I am getting this. I tried it however it is not working. I still get the hours. Empty Dataframe, Columns, Index -are these correct syntax? cause if I use it it gives syntax error.

Comment: @Tasnuva - ya, sometimes if copy from So get syntact error, because bad copied some `''`. Try rewrite solution only.

Comment: No, it didn't. The result was same as before.